# Command Bindings ignored on Modal Popup in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, modal-dialog, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms Photo app (Attached) that is used to take pictures using the native code (iOS ) implementation

App.xaml.cs

```
  public App() {
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new StartPage());
  }
```

StartPage.xaml.cs

This has 2 functions

```
  private async void FullScreen_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)   {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new TakePicturePage(), true);
  }

  private async void Modal_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new TakePicturePage(), true);
  }
```

When launching Navigation.PushAsyncModel the page loads but the command is never raised

The code is as follows for TakePicturPage is as follows

```
public TakePicturePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new TakePictureViewModel(DependencyService.Get<ICameraProvider>());
    }
```

XAML Code

```
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"         x:Class="CameraApplication.Views.TakePicturePage">
        <StackLayout>
                  <Button Text="Take a Picture Test" Command="{Binding TakePicture}" />
                  <Image Source="{Binding Picture}"/>
        </StackLayout>
 </ContentPage>
```

Sample code available at:-

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/72771/command-bindings-ignored-on-modal-popup-page/p1?new=1

Comment: What is not working? Are you setting the `BindingContext` of the page that might be overriding children's BindingContext that you set in the code shown?

Comment: Well basically the button commands do not work and when i push the buttons, no events are raised where as when the page is on a normal page, it works

Comment: updated the question so it makes more sence